# Show Data From DB In Several CSS Div Box

Tags: php, css

I'm new in web development. Can you solve my following issue ?

I'm getting all data from mysql database with following query :

```
<?php
require_once("user_menu.php");
echo "<h2>All Keywords</h2>";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keywords"); 

while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
echo "<div id='keywords'>";
$keywordName = $result['keywordName'];
echo $keywordName."<br/>";
echo "</div>";  
}
?>
```

I want to show the data look like following picture:

[image]

But It's not showing like that It's showing only one value in one div box with following CSS Code:

```
#keywords{
    height:400px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
    padding:10px;   
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need a foreach statement in your PHP code so you can output each result in a cell or div or whatever. No idea where that CSS comes from or what do you intend to do with it so can't tell

Comment: @Fabio this id #keywords comes from CSS file and I've lots of data in my db and I want to show it by column by column with fixed height. So One div box it will contain 20 values. If I've 100 keyword then 5 dive box will be print.

Comment: @Fabio where I need to use `foreach` statement, in while statement ? how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HTML **table** . Let the number of columns be 4 as in the demo.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keywords"); 
echo '<table>';
$count = 0;
while($result =  mysql_fetch_array($query)){
if ($count%4==0 && $count!=0) echo '</tr><tr>';
elseif($count==0) echo '<tr>';
$keywordName = $result['keywordName'];
echo '<td>'.$keywordName."</td>";
$count++;  
}
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm checking it.

Comment: Can I use div class or Id from CSS ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Did the code output the format you wanted?

Comment: You can mark my answer as correct ,if it did what you wanted :)